How can I get apache2 to redirect to snap nextcloud on my home server?
I have quite basic knowledge regarding my goal.
I have both apache2 installed on port 80, and Nextcloud installed on port 82. At the moment I can access "Apache2 Default Page" at 10.1.1.171, and I can access Nextcloud at 10.1.1.171:82.
What I would like to do on the home network is enter "nextcloud"or "nextcloud.local", or whatever,  into  a browser, and be directed to 10.1.1.171:82.
I have the following code as a template
    ServerName your_domain.com  # Replace with your domain name
    ServerAlias www.your_domain.com

    ProxyPass / http://your_nextcloud_ip:your_nextcloud_port/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://your_nextcloud_ip:your_nextcloud_port/

    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPassReverseCookiePath /

    <Proxy *>
        Require all granted
    </Proxy>
</VirtualHost>

and I have modified the easy bits so I now looks like
    ServerName your_domain.com  # Replace with your domain name
    ServerAlias www.your_domain.com

    ProxyPass / http://10.1.1.171:82/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://10.1.1.171:82/

    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPassReverseCookiePath /

    <Proxy *>
        Require all granted
    </Proxy>
</VirtualHost>

but I can go no further, without help.
I don't know what "your_domain.com" should be replaced with given that it is only a local network.  I assume that the working code should be placed in /etc/apache2/sites-available and then enabled, but I have been wrong before.   Thanks.

I think I have got it working, after a fashion.   I have substitured "nextcloud.imac.lan" for " your_domain.com" and can now access Nextcloud by entering "imac.lan/nextcloud" into the browser.  I would like to be able to use "nextcloud.imac.local", which I think needs investigating how sub-domains work.

Start With Official Examples.  You want to combine Using the ServerPath directive at the bottom with Running different sites on different ports. using the same IP address. In your case 1 virtual host would listen on port 80 and the second would listen on port 82, both resolving to 10.1.1.171 with different document roots.  If you need more than this comment, writing an answer is going to take a bit.  I like to be thorough, but I type one-handed.

Assumptions

OP is using a MacOS version (Gathered from imac.local)
OP is trying to use the Apache Version that shipped with MacOS 10.xx.
OP is trying to install the All-In-One version of NextCloud using a reverse proxy.

Broad Overview
Before we can jump into the meat of the question, which is the Nextcloud setup, we need to get our webserver working.  I know the OP said that was working already, but for completeness sake, I'm going to write this as if I were starting from scratch.  I'll list the broad steps here and then each step will be listed in order and explained.  We must:

Install Homebrew.
Install PHP.
Install Apache.
Test PHP.
Install MySQL/phpMyAdmin
Test phpMyAdmin
Install Docker.
Setup Virtual Hosts in Apache
Download the Nextcloud Docker Image
Create the Reverse Proxy so that the Nextcloud Docker Image can see Apache and vice-versa.

Steps - In Depth

Run /bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install.sh)" from Terminal.app - All one line: Wrap seems to have split this. Optional: Install nano if not comfortable with vi.  We have a lot of editing coming up. Use:

brew install nano


Install PHP: brew install php.  Note that you can use set notation here.  As of this writing php@8.3 is the only version available in the Homebrew repository.
Install an up-to-date version of Apache: brew install httpd. Note that Macs do ship with a version of Apache, but we installed this version to follow the documentation at the Apache website.
Test that PHP installed properly before allowing Apache to serve .php pages: brew services restart php && php --version
Test Apache: brew services restart httpd && httpd -v
Install MySQL: brew install mysql && brew install phpmyadmin.

Stop Here
Start at the top of this document: mac-homebrew-lamp.md, and make the relevant config file changes and reissue step 4 and step 6 after changing. Proceed with: echo "<?php echo phpinfo();" > /opt/homebrew/var/www/info.php && curl -I http://localhost:8080/info.php.  If that command succeeds, secure your MySQL installation with: mysql_secure_installation Note See the MySQL config section of the document linked at the start of this paragraph for more options. Update the configs as noted in the Install myphpadmin section.
If all the config changes and tests pass without error, we can proceed to Step 7.  If any tests fail, let me know in the comments and we can figure out what went wrong.
Continue With Step 7 Here Later.
